# SharePoint site redirecting to Login Page after ADFS Authentication

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, sharepoint-server, sharepoint-foundation, sharepoint-on-prem, adfs

I have configured ADFS in my SharePoint site.

> https://sptest.engro.com/

[image]

ADFS Authentication is working fine but after hitting the Login button the Site **redirects to the Login Mode selection Page**:

[image]

I have added relying party trust in ADFS Server as:

> https://sptest.engro.com/_trust

[image]

I have set same URN on ADFS Machine and SharePoint Machine:

> urn:sharepoint:30614

[image]

I have tried multiple solutions available to resolve this but still don't have success.

I have tried adding Cookie Name in the Web.config

I have tried setting DisableLoopBack to 1 in the Registry settings

but nothing worked and it keeps redirecting to the Login Mode selection Page.

Please Help

Thanks in Advance